# Invalid operation for read only resultset when using select for update nowait in multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, oracle11g

For an Oracle database, the following program will throw SQL exceptions only for some threads. Why downgrading resultSetConcurrency from `CONCUR_UPDATABLE to CONCUR_READ_ONLY`? In a single thread environment this is not happening.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class Main extends Thread {

    public static final String DBURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:DB";
    public static final String DBUSER = "USER";
    public static final String DBPASS = "PASS";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
            new Main().start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try
        {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, DBUSER, DBPASS);
            con.setAutoCommit(false);

            try(PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE1 FOR UPDATE NOWAIT", 
                    ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE))
            {               
                ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

                if (rs.next()) {
                    rs.updateString(1, "12345");
                    rs.updateRow();
                }            
            }
            finally
            {
                con.commit();
                con.close();
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            if(!e.toString().contains("NOWAIT"))
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what exceptions you are getting?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation for read only resultset: updateString
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.BaseResultSet.updateString(BaseResultSet.java:419)
 at Main.run(Main.java:36)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the warnings raised against the result set/statement/connection to see why it was downgraded. With this added after the `executeQuery()` call:

```
SQLWarning warning = pstmt.getWarnings();
while (warning != null)
{
    System.out.println("Warning: " + warning.getSQLState()
        + ": " + warning.getErrorCode());
    System.out.println(warning.getMessage());
    warning = warning.getNextWarning();
}
```

In this case you'll sometimes see:

> Warning: 99999: 17091
>   Warning: Unable to create resultset at the requested type and/or concurrency level: ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired

You're looking for a NOWAIT exception, but you're getting a warning. What isn't clear to me is why you still get a result set in that scenario; but you can at least trap that warning and not go into the result set loop if you see it.

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit strange why sometimes a warning is raised instead of an exception

Comment: @IonuțU - I guess it's a warning *because* it does get a result set; if it didn't then it would be an exception. But that doesn't really explain what it's doing *8-) Maybe it's a driver bug, or a DB bug, but I can't see anyone else complaining about this particular scenario. I could only generate it intermittently when trying to force it; I guess you saw it somewhere in a real high-load situation?

Comment: Yes, in a production environment :). As an observation this happens for WAIT timeout clause also and not for SKIP LOCKED (at least in my tests)